# Best practice for passing secrets to Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I'm working on a Design Automation which exports IFC, DWGs, PDFs, etc. from a given Revit file and uploads the results to ACC. Since it is not possible to predict the files without Revit I can't use the `result` configuration to automatically upload the output files, but instead need to use a custom upload implementation based on `System.Net.HttpClient` like https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/upload-large-file-chunks-s3-signed-url-opennetwork-revit-design-automation.

Since the export takes multiple hours, I'm unable to pass a short-lived bearer token (1 hour lifetime) to the design automation, but need to pass `clientId` and `clientSecret` to acquire a token after the export is finished.

Looking a the report I can see both values logged in cleartext, eg.

```
Embedded resource [{"clientId":"xxx","clientSecret":"xxx","hubId":"xxx","projectId":"xxx"}] is saved as a file in 'Unicode' at: 'T:\Aces\Jobs\xxx\config.json'.
```

This seems very problematic. Is there a way to mask these values in the log or an alternative to passing secrets as parameters/json?

Comment: Yes, we can improve to mask secrets in the logs. But the WorkItem's report.log should be only accessible to those who submitted the WorkItem. It is not masked in report.log for diagnosis purpose in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I undestand. The `clientSecret` is correctly masked in the first log entry (`Job information`) but not when logging `Embedded resource`.